Ubuntu 22.04: I cannot start my browser automatically once logged in
Basically I want to login in my system and let the system to open for me my Web browser (Thorium).
Since I' using Ubuntu 22.04 and I want to start the browser as user (and not as root), I followed this instruction carefully (using the --user option and putting my .service script in the systemd/user folder).
So I have now this configuration:
ubuntu@B1:/etc/systemd/user$ cat thorium.service 
[Unit]
Description=Thorium Web Browser

[Service]
#User=myuser
#Group=mypass
ExecStart=/opt/scripts/thorium_start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

where the AppImage of Thorium is started from this script:
ubuntu@B1:/etc/systemd/user$ cat /opt/scripts/thorium_start.sh 
#!/bin/bash

filename="/opt/thorium/Thorium.AppImage"
logfile="/tmp/log.txt"

echo "Starting Thorium" > ${logfile}
echo date >> ${logfile}

sleep 30  # <= Added because I though that probably a delay makes sense

if [[ -f "$filename" ]]; then
    $filename;
else
    echo "$filename not found";
fi

and by the way:
ubuntu@B1:/etc/systemd/user$ systemctl --user is-enabled thorium.service
enabled

and
ubuntu@B1:/etc/systemd/user$ ls -l
insgesamt 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug  9  2022 ayatana-indicators.target.wants
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug  9  2022 default.target.wants
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug  9  2022 graphical-session-pre.target.wants
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug  9  2022 pipewire.service.wants
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   52 Nov 28  2022 pipewire-session-manager.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-media-session.service
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 21  2023 sockets.target.wants
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  152 Jul 11 23:15 thorium.service

thus the .service file has been correctly configured to start at boot and has execution rights.
But the problem is that after login no broswer starts.
Doing from terminal a simple:
$./thorium_start.sh 

starts the browser as expected, so I do not think that the problem is the script.
Any help?
My system is:
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy


Did you consider using the Startup Applications mechanism? See also Autostart Of Applications During Startup

Yes it works man!

At the end @steeldriver pointed me to the right direction.
The startup application mechanism worked. To be more precise, passing as command the .AppImage didn't work but passing the bash script above without any change, worked.
